# check input next of every div with class

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i was trying to check all the inputs when i load the page.

My html was:

```
    <td class="even bundlecheckbox">
    <input onclick="bundle.changeSelection(this)" class="checkbox bundle-option-1 validate-one-required-by-name" id="bundle-option-1-2" type="checkbox" name="bundle_option[1][]" value="2"></td>
```

It repeats maybe 10 or maybe 4 times.

I try to make it with jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.bundlecheckbox').next('input').prop("checked",true);
});
```

But i think i was missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is a children of td class `.bundlecheckbox` it is not sibiling or next element

```
jQuery('.bundlecheckbox').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true);
```

change value and disabled

```
jQuery('.bundlecheckbox').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("value", "3");
jQuery('.bundlecheckbox').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", true)
```

Comment: Thanks, and, how can i change the class / value and disabled attribute of input type="text" ?

Answer (score 3):

`Checkbox` is a child so use [Descendant Selector ("ancestor descendant")](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

> Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

*Use*

```
jQuery('.bundlecheckbox input:checkbox').prop("checked",true);
```

*OR*, You can also use `.find()`, `.children()`

```
jQuery('.bundlecheckbox').find('input:checkbox').prop("checked",true);
```